# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement (Apple Music Kit)

Tags: android, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, apple-musickit

I am using Apple Music Kit in my android application and while uploading signed APK to the google play store it is giving me an error:

```
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
The following APKs or app bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [2]
Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code that it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app
```

I used APK Analyzer and I found out that apple music kit libs are not present in the `X86, X86_64, and arm64-v8a` and it is present in the `armeabi-v7a` only. As shown in the image:

[image]

I checked the Apple music SDK kit and they are not providing any separate SDK for the 64 bit here is the link for [Apple music SDK](https://developer.apple.com/musickit/)

How do I add this lib to 64 bit?

I have added ndk to defaultConfig in gradle file:

```
ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'armeabi', 'mips', 'x86_64'
 }
```

I tried this as well but still facing the same issue:

```
ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi', 'mips'
        }
```

I have added these two lined for the release build:

```
 minifyEnabled true
 shrinkResources true
```

How do I solve this issue? Without this google will not allow me to publish the APK. Can we upload the build only with 32 bit?

Comment: What version of the Apple Music SDK are you using? I see that 1.1.1 has `arm64-v8a` as well as `armeabi-v7a`.

Comment: I am using the 1.1.1 version only and apple support `arm64-v8a`, as well as `armeabi-v7a`  but not `x86`, do you know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You cannot force Apple to ship x86 binaries, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: yes, we can't force apple, that's what I need without solving this I can not publish my app on the play store. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: "without solving this I can not publish my app on the play store" -- yes, you can. It just will not work with x86 devices. That is mostly Chromebooks and other Chrome OS devices. If Apple Music is a secondary feature of your app, you can arrange try to load their NDK libraries and "gracefully degrade" if they do not load, such as due to CPU architecture concerns.